# remove a text after a html tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to remove the text `A text` after the `input` html tags so that I can replace it with another text, let's say, `new text`

```
<input></input>A text
```

to

```
<input></input>new text
```

How do you do it using angular js?

Comment: I don't really understand, what exactly you want... Try to rephrase the question

Comment: @doodeec Rephrased a bit but the question shows my goal. Removing a text after a html tag.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you already have the markup and want to remove/replace existing text with some other text? Or you want to create markup where you can define and change this text?

Comment: @doodeec I already have the markup and just want to remove and replace the existing text with some other text.

Comment: why don't you just use jQuery? I think there isn't a simple way how to do this in angular, when you can't change the markup

Comment: @doodeec How would you do it in Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AngularJs, just assign the text to a scope var in your controller (e.g. named `myController`):

```
$scope.textAfterInput = "A text";
```

Somewhere further in your controller, have a function with changes this:

```
$scope.changeTextAfterInput = function() {
   $scope.textAfterInput = "new text";
};
```

In your html you just use the scope var:

```
<div ng-controller="myController>
   <input type="text" ng-model="myModel">{{textAfterInput}}
   ...
</div>
```

PS An `input` tag does not have a closing tag.